# Open Image in New Window did not work at Safari's Web Inspector mode

Tags: macos, safari, macbook-pro, google-chrome

I opened a [website](http://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a1z10.15.w4011-4047401017.155.knMvfk&id=37435466600&rn=3689382910c5d575f755e16569f8d589) in Safari, opened **Show Web Inspector**, selected one of images from the **Images** folder, right-clicked and selected **Open Image in New Window**, and it did not open a new folder.

I used Chrome and used **Inspect Element**- **Open Image in New Tab**, and Chrome opened the image in new tab.

Is there some problem with Safari or my MacBook Air?

[image]

Comment: I suspect you meant 'open in a new window' not 'open in a new folder.' In any case, this occurs for me as well in Safari 7.0.2 (9537.74.9). For the record, the other options, 'Download Image' and 'Copy Image' work as expected. I just filled out a feedback form @ apple here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html and described the problem. You should take a minute and send feedback as well.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thank you, I have filled out a feedback, too.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to fix safari issue

1. Go to Develop --> User Agent --> Safari ...
2. Select it and do inspect then you can see the button on left side top corner.
3. Now set to default setting by redoing the first point.

[image]